# Magento2.2: How to disable cache for homepage only?

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, home-page

I am using varnish cache and also I've added AMP pages for mobile view. Now the thing is varnish is not detecting mobile and tab so I want to disable varnish for the homepage.

Everything was working fine when I added `cacheable="false"` in default.xml in theme folder but it will make whole website cacheable="false". I just want to disable for the homepage.

Comment: maybe you must work on device detection issue, not disabling cache???

Comment: yeah, this answer solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778976/6536977

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

**Method 1:**

Add the below code to **homepage** cms under

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

content -> pages -> select homepage -> under design tab -> Layout update xml

**Method 2 :**

If you want it via xml in the sense add the below code into

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**cms_index_index.xml** under layout folder.

> NOTE : Disabling cache would certainly lower your site performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I applied method 1 and it worked. Will it disable cache for only home page?

Comment: Yes, to whichever page u placed that code will be effective only on those pages